# Alternative To Exception Control Flow in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, n-tier-architecture

I have read that exception control flow is a bad idea.

```
if(products.length == 0)
   throw new CustomException("Product is required");
```

I am using ajax at the moment for my requests and if a 500 error happens I catch them in an Exception filter that returns the exception in a strongly typed object that is sent to the client in JSON to be shown in a popup. In an ASP.NET MVC applicacation what is the better alternative and an example?

Comment: Do you mean for validation? What aside from input validation are you handling with exception control flow?

Comment: I believe only validation is being used.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for validation purposes of the model it would be better to use standard techniques such as data annotations or if you are like me and find them difficult to use in complex validation scenarios you could also checkout [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).